# Counting triangles that include an edge in R iGraph

Tags: r, igraph, counting, edges

iGraph can count the number of triangles that include each vertex using `igraph::count_triangles()`. Is there a similar function that will provide this count for edges, or an efficient way to use the output from `igraph::triangles()` to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a typo in @ThomasIsCoding's code. Specifically, `, simplify = FALSE)` appears twice. Correcting this, and adding a few lines to add the triangle counts as igraph edge weights gives:

```
triangles <- subset(as.data.frame(table(data.frame(do.call(rbind,unlist(apply(matrix(igraph::triangles(G), nrow = 3), 2, function(x) combn(sort(x), 2, simplify = FALSE)),recursive = FALSE))))), Freq > 0)
    triangles$edge <- igraph::get.edge.ids(G, as.numeric(as.vector(unlist(t(triangles[,1:2])))))
    igraph::E(G)$weight <- 0
    igraph::E(G)$weight[triangles$edge] <- triangles$Freq[triangles$edge]
```

This seems to be fairly fast, even for large dense graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may have to implement it by yourself. The code below might give you some hints

```
aggregate(
  cnt ~ .,
  cbind(
    data.frame(
      do.call(
        rbind,
        unlist(
          apply(
            matrix(triangles(kite), nrow = 3),
            2,
            function(x) combn(sort(x), 2, simplify = FALSE),
            simplify = FALSE
          ),
          recursive = FALSE
        )
      ),
      cnt = 1
    )
  ), sum
)
```

or

```
subset(
  as.data.frame(
  table(
    data.frame(
      do.call(
        rbind,
        unlist(
          apply(
            matrix(triangles(kite), nrow = 3),
            2,
            function(x) combn(sort(x), 2, simplify = FALSE),
            simplify = FALSE
          ),
          recursive = FALSE
        )
      )
    )
  )
), Freq > 0)
```

which gives a data.frame like below

```
   X1 X2 cnt
1   1  2   1
2   1  3   2
3   1  4   3
4   2  4   3
5   3  4   2
6   2  5   2
7   4  5   2
8   1  6   2
9   3  6   2
10  4  6   3
11  2  7   2
12  4  7   3
13  5  7   2
14  6  7   2
15  6  8   1
16  7  8   1
```

## Dummy Data

```
kite <- make_graph("Krackhardt_Kite")
```